# Xamarin Forms App Crash on Startup with One Plus 5t

Tags: nullpointerexception, xamarin.forms, startup, android-8.0-oreo

I'm unable to find the cause of this startup crash. It occurs on my One Plus 5t running Android 8, I don't know about other devices.
Target api: 26 (I've tried setting this to 23 too)
Minimum: 15 (I've tried setting this to 23 too)
Linking: none
Device: One Plus 5t

This is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setTranslationZ(float)' on a null object reference
at android.view.View$4.setValue(View.java:24481)
at android.view.View$4.setValue(View.java:24479)
at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1379)
at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:990)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentFraction(ValueAnimator.java:654)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(ValueAnimator.java:617)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1046)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1065)
at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:852)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.startWithoutPulsing(ValueAnimator.java:1058)
at android.animation.AnimatorSet.handleAnimationEvents(AnimatorSet.java:1142)
at android.animation.AnimatorSet.doAnimationFrame(AnimatorSet.java:1046)
at android.animation.AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(AnimationHandler.java:146)
at android.animation.AnimationHandler.-wrap2(Unknown Source:0)
at android.animation.AnimationHandler$1.doFrame(AnimationHandler.java:54)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:964)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:778)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:710)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:952)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Unhandled Exception:

```
Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setTranslationZ(float)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void android.view.View.setTranslationZ(float)
```

Some nuget package was using code not running on some specific devices. Uninstalling unused packages the problem went away